# relative bar plots with ggplot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, scale

I'm trying to take a dataframe and plot it with ggplot like so:

```
library(ggplot2)
success<-sample(1:10,30,replace=TRUE)
animal<-rep(c("cat","dog","bird"),each=10)
trick<-sample(letters[1:10],30,replace=TRUE)

data.plot<-data.frame(success,animal,trick)

ggplot(data.plot,aes(y=success,x=trick,fill=animal))+geom_bar(stat="identity") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))
```

I'm trying to get the scaling to be relative, though (0-100%) for each bar.
This would imply that each bar is the same height (100%), but the colors are divided into the relative proportions of their weight in the total sum of all the observations in each bar on the graph.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
library(dplyr)
data.plot2 <- data.plot %.% 
  group_by(trick) %.%
  mutate(success_rel = success / sum(success) * 100)
ggplot(data.plot2,aes(y=success_rel,x=trick,fill=animal))+geom_bar(stat="identity") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))
```

Comment: Yes, that's it!  Can you talk a bit about the construction of 'data.plot2'?  The '%.%', 'group_by', and 'mutate'?

Comment: Well `%.%` chains together several commands, `group_by` creates subsetted data frames for each trick group, and `mutate` calculates and adds another column within each subsetted data frame. All together is put back into data.plot2. Here is more on how `dplyr`works: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr.

Comment: I've done some looking around for %.% and it looks like it's pretty specific to (or at least appears a lot with) dplyr.  Why do you need to chain commands together and not just execute them one right after another as usual?  Sorry if this is inane, but I've always had some trouble getting a grip on the %whatever% operators in R

Comment: @BrocolliRob To me it`s better readable than something like `mutate(group_by(data.plot, trick), success_rel = success / sum(success) * 100)` (especially when there are more chained commands).